# Adding text to all posts of certain category in wordpress using MySQL

Tags: wordpress, insert, posts

I have some blog. In one of my category i have 500 posts. I need to insert one simply link on the top of all of this posts which are for example cat=5.

How can i do it using mysql?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do it in mysql, you can use a hook.
Something like that:

```
function append_content($content) {
    global $post;
    if (in_category( 5, $post )) {
       $original = $content;
       $content = "<div class=\"ikaz\">";
       $content .= "hello all";
       $content .= "</div>";
       $content .= $original;
       return $content;  
    }
}

add_filter( 'append_content', 'like_content' );
```